# Matrix powers up to multiplicative factor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, projective-geometry

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix, $A_n = A^n$, and

$$ \bar A_n = \lbrace\alpha A_n, \alpha\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace.$$

I am interested in characterizing the behavior of $\bar A_n$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$. My initial lead is to start with a Jordan decomposition of $A$. But I guess that it is a standard question that should already be studied, so I am looking for references. I have seen several documents addressing the convergence of the sequence $A_n$ to $0$ or $\infty$. Can someone indicate references for the 'projective version' of the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: If all the entries in $A$ are positive (such as with row stochastic or doubly stochastic matrices), then the Perron-Frobenius theorem explains the behavior of $\frac{A^n}{\rho(A)^n}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ quite well where $\rho(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of $A$.

Comment: Following up on Joseph Van Name's comment, all you need is an eigenvalue of multiplicity one whose absolute value exceeds (strictly) that of all other eigenvalues (as in the strong version of the P-F theorem). Then you get $A^n/\rho^n$ converges exponentially quickly. With more than one eigenvalue of largest modulus, convergence, nonconvergence, or periodicity can occur, you simply have to analyze the behaviour of its blocks in Jordan normal form). I doubt there are references because it requires only straightforward techniques.